# About Snell's law and Fresnel equation

Tags: optics, refraction

I'm currently studying optics with Hecht's book.

I got some questions about Snell's law and Fresnel equation.

When $\theta_i = \theta_p$(the polarization angle), as $\theta_p+\theta_t=\frac\pi2$, by Snell's law, $\tan\theta_p=\frac{n_t}{n_i}$.

However, for $\theta_p,$ by Fresnel's equation, $r_{\mid\mid}=\frac{\frac{n_t}{\mu_t}\cos\theta_p-\frac{n_i}{\mu_i}\sin\theta_p}{\frac{n_t}{\mu_t}\cos\theta_p+\frac{n_i}{\mu_i}\sin\theta_p}=0$.

Then $\frac{n_t\mu_i}{n_i\mu_t}=\tan\theta_p$.

Therefore, $\frac{\mu_i}{\mu_t}\tan\theta_p=\tan\theta_p$.

Why this is happens? I can't figure out what is wrong on my calculation.

Comment: Doesn't *Section 8.6.1 An Application of the Fresnel Equations* provide you with an answer? The relevant equations appear towards the end of *Section 4.6.2 Fresnel equations*.